# How do I host a landing page with its own design on an existing Shopify website?

Tags: html, shopify

I have designed a landing page and do not want to host it on a separate subdomain.

I want to host it in my Shopify account as a page of an existing Shopify website. For example: mysite.com/page/the-landing-page

The design is completely different from the main website's design. It will/should use its own CSS/JS files.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why did you bother asking the exact same question twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only options for you are within the Shopify system. Your exact options are like this:

- take over the home page as landing page, so domain.com/landingpage
- as a page, so domain.com/page/landingpage
- as a product, so domain.com/products/landingpage
- as a collection, so domain.com/collections/landingpage
- as a blog article...

So you have a lot of choice. I would go with the page. Easiest to manage for the Shopify merchant.